# Is there a good way to bound rational functions that contain square roots of polynomials?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is there a good way to bound rational functions that contain square roots of polynomials?  Take for example the function $\phi:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$
\frac{l(x)}{\sqrt{q(x)}}
$$
where $l$ denote a linear polynomial and $q$ denotes a quadratic that we assume is nonnegative over $x\in[0,1]$.  We have something that's almost like a linear polynomial over a linear polynomial, but not quite.  Nevertheless, I'm pretty sure that $\phi$ is bounded by the endpoints,
$$
\phi(x) \leq \max\{\phi(0),\phi(1)\}
$$
but I'm not sure how to prove it as the square root gets in the way.

Normally, I would try to prove something like this with a monotonicity argument using the derivative of $\phi$.  If we're increasing or decreasing, we know that the maximum occurs at the endpoints. That said, this argument doesn't seem to work in this case.  Here,
$$
\phi^\prime(x) = \frac{\sqrt{q(x)}l^\prime(x) - l(x)\frac{1}{2}q(x)^{-1/2}q^\prime(x)}{q(x)}
$$
If we assume that, $l(x) > 0$, $l^\prime(x)<0$, $q(x)>0$, $q^\prime(x)<0$, then we have
$$
\phi^\prime(x) = \frac{(+)(-) - (+)(+)(-)}{(+)} = \frac{(-) + (+)}{(+)}
$$
and it's not straightforward to say that this is strictly positive or negative.

Is there a good way to determine where $\frac{l(x)}{\sqrt{q(x)}}$ attains it maximum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-\frac12)^2+1}}$$

reaches it's maximum at $x=\frac12$ which is not an endpoint. So no, your initial idea is not correct.

I don't see any other way of calculating the maximum of $\phi$ other than checking for zeroes of the derivative.